# CRTP pattern with variable Base

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17

Assume that one has two base classes `Base1` and `Base2` for which CRTP pattern is desired.

```cpp
template <typename TDerived>
class Base1 {
};

template <typename TDerived>
class Base2 {
};
```

Now I would like to define a `Derived` class such that it can be "parametrized" with a base one.
What would be the proper way to define it in C++ (C++17 if that matters)?

Below is a pseudo-C++ code

```cpp
template <template <typename> class TBase>
class Derived : public TBase<Derived<TBase>> {}; // Recursion problem here
```

In reality such a derived class is an extension that is applicable to any base class.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is so called [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Of course, you are right. I typed too quickly. I'll modify the original post. The problem I think still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> The problem I think still exists.

Consider your own pseudo-code when fed to a compiler (and some addition):

```
template <typename TDerived>
struct Base1 {
    auto get() const -> int {
        return static_cast<TDerived const*>(this)->a;
    }
};

template <typename TDerived>
struct Base2 {
    auto get() const -> int {
        return static_cast<TDerived const*>(this)->b;
    }
};

template <template<typename> typename TBase>
struct Derived : TBase<Derived<TBase>> {
    int a;
    int b;
};

auto main() -> int {
    auto b = Derived<Base1>{};

    b.a = 1;
    b.b = 2;

    return b.get();
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/457d7EG9q)

As you can see, that pattern is no problem for the compiler.

> Now I would like to define a Derived class such that it can be "parametrized" with a base one. What would be the proper way to define it in C++ (C++17 if that matters)?

The way you posted it in the question is the right way, and works all the way to C++98.

---

You seem to state that there's a recursion problem here, but there is not.

You have a template class `Derived` with a template template parameter `Base1`. The compiler now "knows" that this type `Derived<Base1>`. It is incomplete though, until the `}` is reached.

Then the compiler sees the base, which is `TBase<something>`, which is `Base1` with some template parameter. `Base1` need to be instantiated. The `something` is `Derived<Base1>`, which is an incomplete type.

The compiler then instantiate `Base1` with `Derived<Base1>`. During that process, you cannot use `Derived<Base1>` in a way that it would require it to be complete.

Now that the base is instantiated and a complete type, the compiler finishes to instantiate `Derived<Base1>`, now complete.

There is no recursion here.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I stated the "recursion" problem which is not there. Many thanks for the explanation. I think there is a gap in my understanding of incomplete types which confused me and made me ask the original question. I'll read your answer more thoroughly in the meantime. Again, thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll accept the answer and may be come up with a follow up one if needed.